# Relation on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have problem to get relation in laravel controller.

i want to get data on Read model, and that is has related to Notif Model.

this is code in controller :

```
$notifs = Notif::whereHas('statusnya', function ($queryunnotif) {
    $queryunnotif->where('user_id', Auth::user()->employee_id);
}, '<', 1)
->whereHas('readnya', function ($queryunreadnya) {})
->where('following_id', '>=', $notifs->readnya->created_at)
->where('user_request', '!=', Auth::user()->employee_id)
->whereBetween('created_at', [Auth::user()->created_at, Carbon::now()])
->get();
```

I doubt this line

```
->where('following_id','>=', $notifs->readnya->created_at)->
```

Comment: read this document, it could help https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Hi, please clarify your problem and please format you code better. It's hard to understand what issue your are facing.

Comment: plz tell us what's the relationship between `notifs` and `readnya`? and why the `whereHas('readnya', function ($queryunreadnya){})` closure is empty?

Answer (score 0):

We would need to see the database structure and model to be fully confident in answering, but the line you pointed out is certainly suspicious.

```
->where('following_id','>=', $notifs->readnya->created_at)
```

You most likely want id instead of created_at

```
->where('following_id','>=', $notifs->readnya->id)
```